# Animation not working on the all Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have problem in arrow animation on the hover of the Anchor Tag. While I am hover on the first Anchor tag animation working properly and changing style with the JavaScript. But problem is the while I am using multiple Anchor tag it's only work perfect in the first one and while in another Anchor tag java script not working properly.
I try many solution but not fix the issue.
Please give me suggestion on it. I wrote my code below. Thank You.

```js
var timeout;
    var element = document.getElementById("btn");
    element.onmouseover = function (e) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("ab").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("xy").style.display = "block";

      }, 700)
    };
    element.onmouseout = function (e) {
      if (timeout) {
        document.getElementById("ab").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("xy").style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    }
```

```css
 .main-arrow {
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .sec-arrow {

      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .hori,
    .sec-hori {

      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .btn:hover .arrow {
      animation-name: mainrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .btn:hover .hori {
      animation-name: hori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    }

    .btn:hover .sec-hori {
      animation-name: sechori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }

    .btn:hover .sec-arrow {
      animation-name: secondrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }

    .btn:hover .main-arrow {
      animation-name: rotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    #xy {
      display: none;
    }

    /* main */
    @keyframes mainrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }

      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

    }

    /* second */
    @keyframes secondrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }

      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }


    }

    @keyframes hori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }

    }

    @keyframes sechori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }


    }

    @keyframes rotatingarrow {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow" id="ab">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow" id="xy">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn" id="btn">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow" id="ab">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow" id="xy">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="btn">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow" id="ab">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow" id="xy">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>
```

Comment: You've multiple elements with the same id value, that's not valid.

Comment: @robert Longson yes i changed that but still not working well....

Comment: Your question still has invalid id values so if you changed it we can't see where you're still going wrong because you haven't shown us. You may want to ask a new question if your edits would invalidate the existing answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson I cahnged code but Now Javascript not working May you please check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please following the above code :

```js
var myVar;
    function hoverTrue(event) {
      myVar = setTimeout(function () {
          document.querySelector("#xy"+event).style.display = "block";
          document.querySelector("#ab"+event).style.display = "none";
        }, 700);
    }

    function hoverFalse(event) {
        clearTimeout(myVar);
        document.querySelector("#xy"+event).style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("#ab"+event).style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
.btn{
      margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    .main-arrow {
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    .sec-arrow {
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    .hori,
    .sec-hori {
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    .btn:hover .arrow {
      animation-name: mainrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    .btn:hover .hori {
      animation-name: hori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    .btn:hover .sec-hori {
      animation-name: sechori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }
    .btn:hover .sec-arrow {
      animation-name: secondrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }
    .btn:hover .main-arrow {
      animation-name: rotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    .xy {
      display: none;
    }
    /* main */
    @keyframes mainrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }
      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }
      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }
      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }
    }
    /* second */
    @keyframes secondrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }
      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }
      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }
      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }
    }
    @keyframes hori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }
      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }
    }
    @keyframes sechori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }
      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }
    }
    @keyframes rotatingarrow {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="btn" id="btn" onmouseover="hoverTrue('0')" onmouseout="hoverFalse('0')">
    <a href="#" id="qq">
      <span> View More</span>
      </svg>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
        <g class="main-arrow" id="ab0" class="ab"> 
          <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
        <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy0">
          <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn" onmouseover="hoverTrue('1')" onmouseout="hoverFalse('1')">
    <a href="#">
      <span> View More</span>
      </svg>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
        <g class="main-arrow" id="ab1">
          <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
        <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy1">
          <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="btn" onmouseover="hoverTrue('2')" onmouseout="hoverFalse('2')">
    <a href="#">
      <span> View More</span>
      </svg>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
        <g class="main-arrow" id="ab2">
          <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
        <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy2">
          <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
          <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the id of `ab` and `xy` to class instead.
If you use the same id, only the first element will take effect.

Then again, you gotta edit your javascript too.

** update **
Instead of directly adding the styling, you may try adding a class to edit the hover behavior.

P.S. I've updated the javascript for btn1 only.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

var timeout1;


btn1.onmouseover = function(e) {
 timeout1=  setTimeout(function(){
  
   document.getElementById('xy1').classList.add('display-block');
    document.getElementById('ab1').classList.add('display-none');
  }, 700);

};

btn1.onmouseout = function(e) {
 
 if(timeout1){
    document.getElementById('xy1').classList.remove('display-block');
    document.getElementById('ab1').classList.remove('display-none');
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
 }

};
```

```css
.main-arrow {
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .sec-arrow {

      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .hori,
    .sec-hori {

      transform-box: fill-box;
      transform-origin: center;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    .btn:hover .arrow {
      animation-name: mainrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .btn:hover .hori {
      animation-name: hori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    }

    .btn:hover .sec-hori {
      animation-name: sechori;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }

    .btn:hover .sec-arrow {
      animation-name: secondrotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.7s;
    }

    .btn:hover .main-arrow {
      animation-name: rotatingarrow;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    
    /* added new class */
    .btn:hover .display-none , .xy {
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    .btn:hover .display-block {
      display: block  !important;
    }

    /* main */
    @keyframes mainrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }

      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

    }

    /* second */
    @keyframes secondrotatingarrow {
      0% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13");
      }

      30% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L12 7L10.5 13");
      }

      65% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L14 7L10.5 13");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13");
      }


    }

    @keyframes hori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }

    }

    @keyframes sechori {
      0% {
        d: path("M16 7L5 7");
      }

      100% {
        d: path("M16 7L0 7");
      }


    }

    @keyframes rotatingarrow {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn" id="btn1">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow ab" id="ab1">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy1">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="btn" id="btn2">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow ab" id="ab2">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy2">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="btn3">
    <span> View More</span>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" id="svg-ax">
      <g class="main-arrow ab" id="ab3">
        <path class="hori" d="M16 7L0 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L16.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
      <g class="second-arrow xy" id="xy3">
        <path class="sec-hori" d="M16 7L5 7" stroke="#00AEEF" />
        <path class="sec-arrow" d="M10.5 0.999999L10.5 7L10.5 13" stroke="#00AEEF" />

      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>
```

Comment: yes I made that mistake. But On hover I need to display none and block elements with JavaScript. If you comment JavaScript in my code then on hover all animation running well. but while I apply JavaScript again same issue only first anchor tag working and another not working.

Comment: but both "ab" and "xy" are disply at that time i need to display one and on hover ab is hidden after animation and xy become block. and on mouse leave xy become hidden and ab display block

Comment: instead of changing the style, Adding a new class and altering the styles to the button when hovered seems to do the trick. I've only applied it to button1 though

Comment: @joohoong89 let me check it and thank you so much for your attantion